# Create deterministic archives in C#

Tags: c#, .net, zip, sha

I am writing a .NET app that uploads data to a cloud server (i.e. Dropbox, OneDrive). I use `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip` to compress the folder being uploaded and to extract data pulled from the server. My app needs a method to easily check if the contents of the local file and the contents of the file uploaded are the same **without having to download the file**. The best solution I've found was using the file's hashes and comparing them (Dropbox allows you to get a `content_hash` with their API without downloading the file). However, I noticed that each time I zip the local files, the hash is different. According to my research, zip archives are not deterministic and have different metadata attached to them each time they are zipped, EVEN if the same files are zipped again.

Currently, I've tried the following methods to zip files deterministically:

- Setting compression level to `0`
- Using `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Tar` instead
- Manually changing the dates accessed, modified and created (strangely, the metadata didn't even change after using `File.SetCreationTime()`, `File.SetLastAccessTime()`, etc)

Some notes:

- The files don't have to be uploaded as zips, as long as they are archives containing the content from the folder
- I heard changing the "header bytes" could work but after googling for hours I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this
- If there's another way other than hashing to compare the files without downloading that will work right, I would also be okay doing that (but I haven't found any methods so far)

My current code:

```cs
// Gets the save file's zip data.
// Files are stored on the root directory. Folders are compressed into a folder named after the save file.
public byte[] GetSaveZipData(string name)
        {
            string location = GetSavePath(name);
            FileAttributes attr = File.GetAttributes(location);
            bool isDirectory = attr.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Directory);

            // This entire mess basically just zips the file into what we need. We need to do it manually isntead of using fastzip
            using (var tmpFile = new FileUtils.TemporaryFile()) // Custom temp file that deletes when closed
            {
                using (ZipOutputStream OutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(File.Open(tmpFile.FilePath, FileMode.Open)))
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                    if (isDirectory)
                    {
                        string[] files = FileUtils.GetFileList(location); // Recursively gets all files in the directory
                        foreach (string file in files)
                        {
                            string entryName = Path.Combine(name, file.Substring(location.Length + 1, file.Length - location.Length - 1)); // Stored in <name>/<file-path>
                            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(entryName);
                            OutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
                            {
                                int sourceBytes;

                                do
                                {
                                    sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                    OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
                                } while (sourceBytes > 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(Path.GetFileName(location))
                        {
                            CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Stored
                        };
                        OutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(location))
                        {
                            int sourceBytes;

                            do
                            {
                                sourceBytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                                OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, sourceBytes);
                            } while (sourceBytes > 0);
                        }
                    }
                    OutputStream.Finish();
                    OutputStream.Close();

                    // Read from temporary file
                    var data = File.ReadAllBytes(tmpFile.FilePath);
                    return data;
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated :D

Comment: Make yourself an example, by zipping the same inputs two or more times.  Use a file diff tool that supports binary files to see how much of the file has changed.  Maybe it's just a single field (sequence of 2 or 4 bytes in a row).  See if your favorite ZIP program will still open the file if you change all inconsistent bytes to zero.  Actually, if the example files are created with only a short amount of time passing between, probably only a portion of the field you care about will actually be different, but this would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

The zip files should be identical if all the inputs match. In particular the following need to be identical

1. the data to be compressed is the same
2. the timestamps for the files are identical
3. the zip library/program is the same

Here is an example.

First create a two zip files with the same content

```
$ echo abcd >file.txt
$ zip a.zip file.txt 
  adding: file.txt (stored 0%)
$ zip b.zip file.txt 
  adding: file.txt (stored 0%)
```

Check if they are identical

```
$ cksum a.zip b.zip
4184356362 171 a.zip
4184356362 171 b.zip
```

They are.

I don't know C#, but I suspect the problem you are facing is with the timestamp that the C# library uses when it add entries to your zip file. It is likely that it will default to the current date/time. Try using the `DateTime` property in [ZipEntry](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/help/api/ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipEntry.html) to explicitly set the timestamp for each of the entries in your zip file.